# Python | Convert hexstrings in a list to float

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, hex

I have data-points of hex-strings in a list.

I tried converting the list to string and then to a byte array. As I try to convert the byte array to float it only returns one value.

Code used is :

```
byteArrObj = bytearray(n, 'utf-8')
byteObj = bytes(byteArrObj)
byte8=bytearray.fromhex(b)
print(byte8)
floatvalue = struct.unpack('<f', byte8[:4])
```

This produces a tuple, like `(0.09273222088813782,).

How do I print all the float values from the list?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you expecting `0.927322` from `64 EA BD 3D` or `0.09273222088813782`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make a function that converts one of the values:

```
def hexdump_to_float(text):
    return struct.unpack('<f', bytes.fromhex(text))[0]
```

Notice:

1. I skip the step of finding `byteArrObj` or `byteObj` from your code, because they had no effect in your code and do not help solve the problem.
2. I use the type `bytes` rather than `bytearray` because we don't need to modify the underlying data. (It's analogous to using a `tuple` rather than `list`.)
3. I do not bother with slicing the data, because we already know there will be only 4 bytes, and because `struct.unpack` would ignore any extra data in the buffer anyway.
4. To get the value out of the tuple that `struct.unpack` returns, I simply index into the tuple. That gives me a single `float` value.

So this is a simple one-line function, but it helps to make a function anyway since it gives a clear name for what we are doing.

The next step is to apply that to each element of the list. You can do this easily with, for example, a *list comprehension*:

```
my_floats = [hexdump_to_float(x) for x in my_hexdumps]
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Highly appreciate that.